# cors возвращает ошибку

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

Я делаю fetch-запрос на свой сервер:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ email: 'adaw' })
}).then(res => console.log(res))
```

Но почему-то в возвращаемом промисе `[[PromiseResult]]: undefined`.

К тому же возвращается какой-то непонятный `Response`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код сервера, `*` помечено проблемное место. Здесь можно отправить любой статус ответа, и он также придет с Response, но при этом `[[PromiseResult]]: undefined`

```js
const Router = require('express-promise-router');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const User = require('../models/User');
const config = require('config');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const router = Router();

const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

const corsOptions = {
    origin: config.get('CORS.whiteList'), // http://localhost:3000
    optionsSuccessStatus: config.get('CORS.optionsSuccessStatus') // 200
}

router.post('/login',
    cors(corsOptions),
    jsonParser, [check('email', 'Некоректный email').isEmail()],
    async(req, res) => {
        try {
            const errors = validationResult(req);

            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                return res.status(400).json({                            // * 
                    errors: errors.array()[0].msg,
                    message: 'Некорректные данные при регистрации'
                })
            }

            const candidate = await User.findOne({ email: email });

            if (candidate) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    msg: 'Такой email уже зарегестрирован'
                });
            }

            const user = new User({
                email
            });

            await user.save();

        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json({
                msg: 'Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте снова',
                err: err.stack
            });
        }
    }
);

module.exports = router;
```

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: У вас явно неверно настроен cors на сервере.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, а как можно правильно настроить cors? В чем я ошибся?

Comment: Для cors я использую [эту](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) библиотеку.

Comment: У вас config.get('CORS.whiteList') точно правильно возвращает? И что такое `Router` поддерживает ли он использование бибилиотеки `cors`? Попробуйте для начала для `app.use(cors())` - для всех запросов включить.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, буквально неделю назад этот код работал

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, также пробовал использовать стандартный express router, но все та же ошибка

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, и `app.use(cors())` также прописано

Comment: В вопросе `app.use(cors())`нету. Зачем тогда вы для конкретного роута тоже cors ставите? Покажите ваш код, где `app.use`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, во время деббагинга я выяснил, что ошибка в методе `.json()`. Именно на нем приложение запинается и возвращает Response.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116456/discussion-between-stepan-kasyanenko-and-voprositel).